# Should I mock external web service if my code's sole purpose is to talk to this web service?

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, mocking

I am creating an sdk/client library for a web-service. I understand mocking external dependencies etc using things like wiremock for http. But should I mock the external web service if my code's sole purpose is to talk to this web service? Or should I create two separate test suites - unit testing with mocked out services and another set that perform the full integration tests?

Answer (score 0):

Mocking the external web services make sense. I have used it for Unit Tests alone. It is acceptable practice.